# My permission is denied using Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make an app with kivy but my permission is denied. I installed it the recommended way for xubuntu on the kivy website by adding the ppa and using sudo apt-get. When I run the app the GUI appears but when I press a button that should return some text, the gui closes and I get an error that my class 'MITMs1' does not have an attribute 'self'. I'm also using scapy and i'm on python 2.7.

here is a similar problem  https://i11.at/dwl/eos/kivy30.pdf but my os error is

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/input/event5'
```

My full output is

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/ro/.kivy/logs/kivy_15-12-27_25.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 173 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
 WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <3.0 Mesa 10.3.2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Intel Open Source Technology Center>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Mesa DRI Intel(R) Bay Trail >
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <1.30>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event5
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event5>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
 Exception in thread Thread-1:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
     self.run()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
     self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/input/providers/mtdev.py", line 197, in _thread_run
     _device = Device(_fn)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lib/mtdev.py", line 131, in __init__
     self._fd = os.open(filename, os.O_NONBLOCK | os.O_RDONLY)
 OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/input/event5'

[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "skivy.py", line 76, in <module>
     MITMtool().run()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 824, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 487, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 539, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 300, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 330, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 315, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 281, in post_dispatch_input
     wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "_event.pyx", line 699, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:6856)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors.py", line 163, in on_touch_up
     self.dispatch('on_release')
   File "_event.pyx", line 695, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:6815)
   File "_event.pyx", line 1168, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:11690)
   File "_event.pyx", line 1052, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy/_event.c:10730)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1465, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "<string>", line 23, in <module>
   File "skivy.py", line 64, in run_ifconfig
     + '[color=00ff00][i]{0}[/i][/color]'.format(self.ipv6) + '\n\n'
 AttributeError: 'MITMs1' object has no attribute 'self'
```

My code is

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from scapy.all import *
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from subprocess import check_output

Builder.load_string('''
<MITMs1>:
    BoxLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            id: client_box
            size_hint: 0.5, 1
            spacing: 10
            Label:
                id: device_lbl
                markup: True
                size_hint: 1, 1
                text: 'LABEL! :)'
            TextInput:
                id: iface_name
                size_hint: 1, .2
                text: 'eth0'
                multiline: False
            BoxLayout:
                Button:
                    size_hint: 1, .2
                    text: 'Run Ifconfig'
                    on_release: root.run_ifconfig()
        ScrollView:
            size_hint: 0.5, 1
            do_scroll_x: False
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                id: nodes
                size_hint: 1, None

            ''')

class MITMs1(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MITMs1, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.iface_name = self.ids['iface_name']
        self.device_lbl = self.ids['device_lbl']
        self.client_box = self.ids['client_box']
        self.nodes = self.ids['nodes']

    def run_ifconfig(self):

        self.ifconfig = subprocess.check_output(['ifconfig', self.iface_name.text])
        self.iface, self.my_ip, self.MAC, self.Bcast, self.Nmask, self.ipv6 = (self.ifconfig.split()[i] for i in (0, 6, 4, 7, 8, 11))
        self.device_lbl.text = ('[color=00ff00][i][b]My Device[/b][/i][/color]' + '\n\n' + 'Interface: '
        + '[color=00ff00][i]{0}[/i][/color]'.format(self.iface) + '\n\n' + 'IP: '
        + '[color=00ff00][i]{0}[/i][/color]'.format(self.my_ip[5:]) + '\n\n' + 'MAC: '
        + '[color=00ff00][i]{0}[/i][/color]'.format(self.self.MAC) + '\n\n' + 'Bcast: '
        + '[color=00ff00][i]{0}[/i][/color]'.format(self.Bcast[6:]) + '\n\n' + 'Nmask: '
        + '[color=00ff00][i]{0}[/i][/color]'.format(self.Nmask[5:]) + '\n\n' + 'IP: '
        + '[color=00ff00][i]{0}[/i][/color]'.format(self.ipv6) + '\n\n'
)


class MITMtool(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MITMs1(name='MITMs1'))

if __name__=='__main__':
    MITMtool().run()
```

Comment: The permission thing is not important.

Answer (score 0):

You have `format(self.self.MAC)` in the middle of the string construction. This is why you get the error about not having a `self.self`.

The input error isn't important, it just comes from kivy querying your input devices to see what's available.